# Programming magnetic field in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that computes the magnetic field of dipole and works:

```
import numpy as np
import math
# Dipole function
def dipole(m, r, r0):
    """
    Calculation of field B in point r. B is created by a dipole moment m located in r0.
    """
# R = r - r0 - subtraction of elements of vectors r and r0, .T - transposition of array
    R = np.subtract(np.transpose(r), r0).T
# Spatial components of r are the outermost axis
    norm_R = np.sqrt(np.einsum("i...,i...", R, R))
# Dot product of R and m
    m_dot_R = np.tensordot(m, R, axes=1)
# Computation of B for dipole
    B_d = 3 * m_dot_R * R / norm_R**5 - np.tensordot(m, 1 / norm_R**3, axes=0)
# Abbreviation for B = B * 1e-7, multiplication B of 1e-7, permeability of vacuum: 4\pi * 10^(-7)
    B_d *= 1e-7 
# The result is the magnetic field for dipole B_d
    print(B_d)
    print(B_d.shape)
    print(type(B_d))
    return B_d

# Grid limits
XMIN =-0.15
XMAX = 0.15
YMIN = 0
YMAX = 0.2
ZMIN =-0.15
ZMAX = 0.15
NUM   = 150          # grid resolution 

# Defining dipole
r0_dipole = [-0.02, 0.08, 0]      # dipole position
m_dipole  = [0, 0.1, 0]           # dipole moment
PARTICLE_DISTANCE_EPS = 0.001     # sensitivity to identify particle near the curve line

# Definition of space
X = np.linspace(XMIN, XMAX, num = NUM)
Y = np.linspace(YMIN, YMAX, num = NUM)
Z = np.linspace(ZMIN, ZMAX, num = NUM)

# Components of magnetic fiels computed with function dipole
Bx_d, By_d, Bz_d = dipole(m = [0.05, 0.03, 0], r=np.meshgrid(X, Y, Z), r0=r0_dipole)
```

How to write a similar function that will compute the magnetic field according to these equations?

[image]

I tried:

```
def get_b(grid):
    B_theta = 0
    if grid[2].any() < 0:
        B_z = grid[0]
        B_R = 0
    elif grid[2].any() < np.pi:
        B_z = 0.25 * grid[0] * math.cos(grid[2]) + 0.75 * grid[0]
        B_R = (0.25/3) * grid[0] * grid[0] * math.sin(grid[2])
    else:
        B_z = 0.5 * grid[0]
        B_R = 0
    return (B_R, B_theta, B_z)

import numpy as np
# Grid limits
RMIN = 0.000001
RMAX = 1
THETA_MIN = 0
THETA_MAX = 2*np.pi
ZMIN =0
ZMAX = 2

# Definition of space
R = np.linspace(RMIN, RMAX, num = NUM)
THETA = np.linspace(THETA_MIN, THETA_MAX, num = NUM)
Z = np.linspace(ZMIN, ZMAX, num = NUM)

B_R, B_theta, B_z = get_b(grid=np.meshgrid(R, THETA, Z))
```

However, the result of the function is not in the correct shape. How to rewrite the second function get_b, please?

Comment: If I replace `math.cos` by `np.cos`, there's no shape error. Is this simply what you need?

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped. How to verify that cylindric coordinates are correct? I would like to set z going from left to right, it is an axis of symmetry, R is a distance from the axis, and theta is an angle.

Comment: mixing questions between main body and comments makes it hard to follow : you should edit your question, fix the math->np, and clarify this new question

Comment: OK, thank you. Here is a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855941/how-to-correct-one-of-the-requested-variable-is-out-of-bounds-in-dimension-0-err