# How to correct One of the requested variable is out of bounds in dimension 0 error

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, interpolation

How to correct this program, please? There is an error: ValueError: One of the requested xi is out of bounds in dimension 0.
There is a function for defining the magnetic field according to equations in cylindric coordinates. Then, it should compute steamline using yt module and compute a trajectory of charges particle.

Without the last two lines, it works. However, I am not sure wheater it works correct but there is no error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator,interpn  
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp                   # Runge-Kutta method 
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D                 # 3d graph
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d                 # 3d graph
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import math
from matplotlib import patches
import code
import yt
from yt import YTArray  # arrays in yt module
from yt.visualization.api import Streamlines  # force lines
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

# Configuration file
from configparser import ConfigParser
cfg = ConfigParser()
cfg.read('setting.cfg')

# Font setting
import font

# Constants
q     =-1.6e-19      # electron charge
m     = 9.1e-31      # electron mass
v_par = 2000         # parallel volocity 
v_per = 2000         # perpendicular velocity
NUM   = 150          # grid resolution 

x0=np.zeros(6)      # vector - 6 dim, give zeros into it (3 components - positions, 3 components - velocity)

def get_b(grid):
    B_theta = np.zeros((150, 150, 150), dtype=np.float)
    if grid[2].any() < 0:
        B_z = grid[0]
        B_R = 0
    elif grid[2].any() < np.pi:
        B_z = 0.25 * grid[0] * np.cos(grid[2]) + 0.75 * grid[0]
        B_R = (0.25/3) * grid[0] * grid[0] * np.sin(grid[2])
    else:
        B_z = 0.5 * grid[0]
        B_R = 0
    return (B_R, B_theta, B_z)

import numpy as np
# Grid limits
RMIN = 0.000001
RMAX = 1
THETA_MIN = 0
THETA_MAX = 2*np.pi
ZMIN =0
ZMAX = 2

# Definition of space
R = np.linspace(RMIN, RMAX, num = NUM)
THETA = np.linspace(THETA_MIN, THETA_MAX, num = NUM)
Z = np.linspace(ZMIN, ZMAX, num = NUM)

B_R, B_theta, B_z = get_b(grid=np.meshgrid(R, THETA, Z))

print(B_R)
print(type(B_R))
print(B_R.shape)

# Choose point in field where force line will be integrated
R_point = 0.025
THETA_point = 0.05*np.pi
Z_point = 0

# Dictionary of numpy arrays - magnetic field data
data = dict(B1=B_R, B2=B_theta, B3=B_z) 
B_R = data["B1"]
B_theta = data["B1"]
B_Z = data["B1"]

print(data)

# 3d array of dipole magnetic field 
bbox = np.array([[-0.15, 0.15], [0, 0.2], [-0.1, 0.1]])                               # border


ds = yt.load_uniform_grid(data, B_R.shape, length_unit="Mpc", bbox=bbox, nprocs=100) # data, dimenze


# Define c: the center of the box, chosen point
c = ds.arr([R_point, THETA_point, Z_point], 'code_length')  
c1 = ds.domain_center
# N is number of streamlines
N = 1 
# Scale is the spatial scale of the streamlines relative to the boxsize
scale = ds.domain_width[0] 
pos = c

# Create streamlines and integration
streamlines = Streamlines(ds, pos, 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', length=None) 
streamlines.integrate_through_volume()


# Initial conditions are copied from result below
def fields(t = 0, x=[2.56662842e-02,  4.60688953e-02, 1.50116387e-18]):
    n = len(B_R)
# Interpolate
    B1 = my_3d_interp(R,THETA,Z, B_R, x[0], x[1], x[2])
    B2 = my_3d_interp(R,THETA,Z, B_theta, x[0], x[1], x[2])
    B3 = my_3d_interp(R,THETA,Z, B_Z, x[0], x[1], x[2])
# Results to matrices
    B = np.array([B1, B2, B3]);
    return B

def my_3d_interp(x, y, z, V, xi, yi, zi):
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator as rgi

    interpolating_function = rgi((x, y, z), V)
    return interpolating_function(np.array([xi, yi, zi]).T)

B = fields(t=0, x=[2.56662842e-02,  4.60688953e-02, 1.50116387e-18])

# Formulae
w_c  = abs(q*np.sqrt(sum(np.power(B,2)))/m)/2    # cyclotron frequency, addition of seconds powers of the vector B
dt   = (1/w_c)/100                               # step is 1/100 of characteristic frequency
t0   = 0
tmax = (1/w_c)*15

t  = np.arange(t0,tmax,dt)
rL = abs(v_per/w_c)                              # Larmor radius

# Definition of function for prependicular vector in cases when the multiplication by the vector [1,0,0] fails due to the parallel vector with the basis
def perpendicular_vector(v):
    if v[1] == 0 and v[2] == 0:
        if v[0] == 0:
            raise ValueError('zero vector')
        else:
            return np.cross(v, [0, 1, 0])
    return np.cross(v, [1, 0, 0])

for stream in streamlines.streamlines:
    stream = stream[np.all(stream != 0.0, axis=1)]

# Data of force line
x_streamline = stream[:,0]
y_streamline = stream[:,1]
z_streamline = stream[:,2]


xd = np.array([x_streamline[2]-x_streamline[0], y_streamline[2]-y_streamline[0], z_streamline[2]-z_streamline[0]]) # tangent at the curve's start point
xd_norm=xd/np.linalg.norm(xd)                                                                                      # unit parallel vector
x_par=v_par*xd_norm
perp = perpendicular_vector(xd_norm)                                                                               # random perpendicular vector
perp_norm = perp / np.linalg.norm(perp)                                                                            # normalized perpendicular vector
x_per = v_per * perp_norm                                                                                          # perpendicular velocity
xv = x_par+x_per                                                                                                   # total velocity
temp_norm=np.cross(xd_norm,perp_norm)

# Spatial coordinates of x0 should be near the initial point of force line 
norm_vector=np.cross(xd_norm,perp_norm)/np.linalg.norm(np.cross(xd_norm,perp_norm))

# It is necessary to divide by two
dx_rL = rL * norm_vector/2                                                                                         # difference to the distance of rL, perpendicular to curve starting point
# Convert dx_rL to yt array
dx_rL_yt = ds.arr(dx_rL, 'code_length')

# Initial position
x0[0] = x_streamline[1]+dx_rL_yt[0]
print('aaaaaaaaaa',x0[0])
x0[1] = y_streamline[1]+dx_rL_yt[1]
x0[2] = z_streamline[1]+dx_rL_yt[2]

# These values were copied to functions above
x_start=[x0[0],x0[1],x0[2]]

# Initial velocities
x0[3]=xv[0]
x0[4]=xv[1]
x0[5]=-xv[2]

print('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',x0)
# B magnetic field in the place of particle
def deriv (t, x0):
    q=-1.6e-19          # electron charge
    m=9.1e-31           # electron mass
    B = fields(t,x0)    
    v=[x0[3], x0[4], x0[5]]

    xdot=[v[0],
          v[1],
          v[2],
          q/m*((v[1]*B[2]-v[2]*B[1])),
          q/m*((v[2]*B[0]-v[0]*B[2])),
          q/m*((v[0]*B[1]-v[1]*B[0]))]
    return xdot

# Solution of differential equations
xdot = deriv(t, x0)
solution = solve_ivp(deriv, [t0, tmax], x0, method = "RK45", t_eval = np.arange(t0,tmax,dt))
```

Comment: What library is giving that error? You should tag your question with it.

Comment: I think that `scipy.interpolate `

Comment: Please post [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and full traceback. Now we don't even know where the problem happens.

Comment: I tried to shorten the code. Two last lines caused the error.

Comment: @Archie, in your previous comment you claimed `scipy.interpolate` causes an error, no you claim differently. Your code doesn't seem to be minimal. The full traceback is not provided. It's hard to help in that case.

Comment: I do not know how to provide the minimal code. The computation before are necessary.